# How to trace async database operations in Intellitrace Events?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to see some queries that my application using **EntityFramework** does.
In my method which is not **async** I can see the queries normally:

```
   public List<Tool> GetTools()
   {
        return EntityContext.ToList();
   }
```

[image]

But if its like:

```
  public Task<List<Tool>> GetTools(int quantity)
  {
        return EntityContext.Take(quantity).ToListAsync();
  }
```

Is it possible to get the queries of a **async** method in **IntelliTrace** Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF you can debug to the output window and command line easy enough.  Here is a shortcut method I created.

```
    public void EnableDebugging()
    {
        Database.Log = s =>
                       {
                           Console.Write(s);//windows apps
                           Debug.Write(s);//website apps
                       };
    }
```

Comment: the .Log property does not appear to be present in EF Core.

Answer (score 4):

IntelliTrace does not currently support async ADO.NET events. Please vote for this feature here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/11356578-add-intellitrace-support-for-async-ado-net-events