# Diagnostic Tool in VS does not catch ADO.NET when using ASYNC methods

Tags: debug-diagnostic-tool, diagnostic-tools

I am developing a web API and using asynchronous as much as i can. 
I am using unitOfWork Pattern with Repository Pattern and EF 6.1.3. 
I know that in Diagnostic Tools in VS2015 we can see ADO.NET events and we can check the queries performed against the database (SQL). 
My problem is that i can´t see them...maybe because they are asynchronous.
Is there a way to check the queries performed ? 
I know other tools to do that (SQL Profiler / EF interceptors) but i would like to use the Diagnostic Tools in VS.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34686683/1364358). Not currently supported but the answer gives a link to a feedback page for Visual Studio where you can vote to get it added. Not sure who uservoice are but it appears to be something Microsoft are using for feedback.